# MATLAB boxplot from frequency or from five number summary

Tags: matlab, frequency, boxplot, summary

I have a set of data, in the form of different values and the number of occurrences of each. I would like to do a box plot of the data, but I can't figure out how to do it. Is there some way to get the boxplot function to count each value times the frequency? Or is there a way to do a boxplot from a five number summary?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your second question: Yes, you can perform a boxplot on a 5-number summary.

Sort of. I mean, it just comes down to the fact that the min/Q1/median/Q3/max of your 5-number summary will be exactly those 5 numbers. So you can just call `boxplot` on the summary statistics, though you'll want to disable the outlier detection (which is enabled by default)*:

```
boxplot(summary_stats, 'whisker',Inf)
```

Another approach may be to recreate the original data from your count data, if that isn't impractically large. Here is a somewhat-kludgy way of doing that:

```
OrigDataCells = arrayfun(@(val,reps) repmat(val, [reps 1]), Values, Counts, 'UniformOutput',false);
OrigData = vertcat(OrigDataCells{:});
```

where `Values` and `Counts` are the values and the number of occurrences.

---

<sub>*The default value for the `'whisker'` parameter is 1.5, which caps the whisker length at 1.5 IQR and causes any points beyond that to be displayed as an "outlier". Setting this to infinity will cause the whiskers to extend to the max/min of the data.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Update:

The below description is correct for a 5-element vector. The easiest way to achive the goal plotting a boxplot by its 5 parameters is to double the 25th and 75th percentile element to generate a 7-element vector.

Example:

```
boxplot([min, 25thPerc, 25thPerc, median, 75thPerc, 75thPerc, max]);
```

If a 5-elements Vector instead of the 7-elements vector must be used see the following:

I just came across this post which has already been answered years ago. I just want to add, that just giving 5 figures to the boxplot() method does not work as inteded, as Q1 and Q3 get calcuated on the 5 elements and thus the shown Q1 and Q3 are not always equal to the 2nd and 4th element of the vector. The min, median and max values are right of course.

Matlab calculates the 25th percentile of a N=5 elements vector V the following way:

```
V = [3, 11, 6, 9, 5];
P = 0.25; % 25th percentile

1) Sort:
VS= sort(V); % VS= [3, 5, 6, 9, 11]

2)
I = (P * N) + 0.5 = 1.75;
```

So the value of the element at position I=1.75 of the sorted vector represents the 25th percentile the best. As all elements have integer indices, Matlab uses linear interpolation to find the virtual index I=1.75. As 1.75 lies between element VS(1) and VS(2) and is closer to VS(2), it takes 75% of VS(2) + 25% of VS(1).

```
Result = (ceil(I)-I)*VS(floor(I) + I-floor(I)*VS(ceil(I))

with: 
ceil(I) = 2
floor(I) = 1
ceil(I)-I = 0.25
I-floor(I) = 0.75

Result = 0.25*VS(1) + 0.75*VS(2);
       = 0.25*3 + 0.75*5
       = 4.5
```

So the 25th Percentile of our Vector V is 4.5

In order to get a proper boxplot, the method boxplot() needs to be feeded with the following vector D

```
D = [minV, a, medianV, b, maxV]
```

where minV, medianV and maxV are the minimum, median and maxim values of V.

```
a = (q1 - 0.25*minV) / 0.75;
b = (q3 - 0.25*maxV) / 0.75;
```

with q1 and q3 being the 25th and 75th percentile you want to show up in the boxplot.

Hope this helps :-)